# Parse get query string and use value to change check box state

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to javascript and I am trying to change the state of check boxes by checking for their id in get query string values. For example, if we have the following url `http://localhost/aasd/index.php?category[]=74`, I want to change the checkbox with id 74 to be checked.

I am trying to do it with the code below but it's not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var vars = query.split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split('=');

   document.getElementById(pair[1]).checked = true;

}
```

pair[1] produces undefined74 I cant change check box state with that. I need to pass 74 to `document.getElementById(pair[1]).checked = true;`for the check box to be checked.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you think is in `vars[0]`? Why does your url have "&" immediately after the question mark?

Comment: It happens because vars[0] is equal ''

Comment: check out my answer and link to fiddle.

Comment: @nnnnnn ive removed that now, so its `http://localhost/aasd/index.php?category[]=74`

Comment: And do you still have a problem?

Comment: @nnnnnn ye it doesn't do anything now

Answer (score 0):

try this.. did it with an assumptions that url will have only one parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var url = window.location.href;
  document.getElementById(url.substr(url.indexOf('=') + 1)).checked = true;
});
```

Comment: I need to loop through multiple parameters

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
qsArray = new Array();
var query = "http://localhost/aasd/index.php?category[]=74";
var vars = query.split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split('=');

   $("#"+pair[1]).attr("checked",true); // this will make the checkbox checked when it encounters check box with id 74 I have created a check box with id 74 in my jsfiddle

}

});
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d5wbo91m/2/

Comment: No explanation about why this works? I.e. because `$("#"+pair[1]).attr("checked",true)` will not give an error even if pair[1] is undefined, and you changed the query string to remove the ampersand (although the question has now been updated to do the same).

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't do anything

Comment: @aasd jsfiddle makes the check box state to true on page load

Comment: @aasd `pair[1]` will have all the categories no from the url and if the checkbox with the category id is present it will change the checkbox status to true

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala there is no checkbox in that html?

Comment: "Updated"  fiddle is still the same. No checkbox, and JS that has a syntax error and doesn't match what's in your answer - although using the alert() as in the fiddle is helpful because it shows why the OP's code doesn't work...

Comment: @aasd did you get it now? let me know